# Is there any method to extract "score" produced when querying dataset in MongoDB compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new in learning about MongoDB compass.

How do I extract the highlighted `"score"` produced when we query the data as shown below?

[image: Score]

I tried using `“Export Collection”`, but it doesn’t work. Even if I add a new field (`"score"`) in `'Export Collection"`, a `score` column will be created but it will be empty.

I want to create `"score"` column containing all the `score` for each of the result

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Would you explain further what you want to do with `"score"`?  It's returned in the projection.  Where else do you want it to go?

Comment: I am trying to extract the score into either JSON or CSV. I'm thinking of extracting the score so that I can use it as a target and turn this issue into a machine learning and prediction issue. Can you tell me more about "projection" that you mentioned in your comment?

Comment: _"Projection"_ is what you did on the **`Project`** line.  If you want to export `"score"` and the other fields, you could use Compass's **`Aggregations`** and create a pipeline with the last stage being `"$out"` to another new collection.  Then go to that collection and **`EXPORT COLLECTION`**.